# i am able to navigate but i am getting an error below

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Skpj.png)
`I am new to react native and i am trying to navigate through screen using fire base authentication and stack navigation and i am getting this error

The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Chat"} was not handled by any navigator. `
Do you have a screen named 'Chat'?

Do you have a screen named 'Login'?`your text`

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Piu7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9N4N.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot navigate to the `Chat` page it's not in your navigator if there's no user, to solve this issue you need to make the user in your store provider to force the app to re-render, saving the user in your async storage isn't enought.

For example if you're using redux then you need to store the user inside a state and add a `useSelector` in your router page and when firebase return the user save it inside it that way your router will re-render and replace the routers directly without needing to navigate to Chat like this example:

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.auth);
```

With this code when you save the user inside the reducer your router will re-render and navigate user to the `Chat` page directly.

I can help you with code if you upload the source into github hope you find this helpful.

And you can check this documentation from `react-navigation` from [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/).